# On click Anchor link, change background of div

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have written this code to get the result that on click of Anchor link the background color of the div below it gets changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#l-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#m-under").css("background", "grey");
    $("#l-under").css("background", "blue");
});
$("#m-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#m-under").css("background", "blue");
    $("#l-under").css("background", "grey");
});
</script>
```

But, It is not working. The Background color of Div doesnt get changed on button click. 
Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Additional code(HTML)

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="m-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <div id=m-container-2">
   <a id="m-button" href="#15178671677277-96tu3e-3487" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Mobile</span>
    <div id="m-underline-div"></div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="l-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="l-button" href="#151746716339-c6ryaabc-d953" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
   <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Laptop</span>
   <div id="l-underline-div"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

Update: changed JS to following(but still color not changing)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#l-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#m-underline").removeClass('bluecolorbg');
    $("#m-underline").addClass('greycolorbg');
    $("#l-underline").removeClass('greycolorbg');
    $("#l-underline").addClass('bluecolorbg');  

});

$("#m-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#m-underline").removeClass('greycolorbg');
    $("#m-underline").addClass('bluecolorbg');
    $("#l-underline").removeClass('bluecolorbg');
    $("#l-underline").addClass('greycolorbg')

});
});
```

CSS:

```
.greycolorbg{
    background-color:#c3c3c3;
    background:#c3c3c3;
}
.bluecolorbg{
    background-color:#236df1;
    background:#236df1;
}
```

---

Update: For some reason .click is making things work, instead of .on

```
$("#l-button").click(function() {
```

Comment: what do you mean by `It is not having the intended effect`. I suggest to have a class with the desired style then use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

Comment: Would you be able to provide the HTML bit that you are using?

Comment: Reason for Jquery .on is not working. 1) Might be your jquery library is old. 2) Your DOM have more than one #id which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

change `$("#id").css("background", color);` to `$("#id").css("background-color", color);`

See reference here : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#l-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#l-container").css("background", "grey");
    $("#m-container").css("background", "blue");
});
$("#m-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#l-container").css("background", "blue");
    $("#m-container").css("background", "grey");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div id="m-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <div id=m-container-2">
   <a id="m-button" href="#15178671677277-96tu3e-3487" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Mobile</span>
    <div id="m-underline-div"></div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="l-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="l-button" href="#151746716339-c6ryaabc-d953" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
   <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Laptop</span>
   <div id="l-underline-div"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please try like this demo. Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [Change div background color on link click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237578/change-div-background-color-on-link-click)

Answer (score 0):

I would do a different approach. Instead the use of ID's I would give it a class name which you can easily insert or remove items and your JS code will not have to be changed.

```
<a id="m-button" href="#15178671677277-96tu3e-3487" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="btn-anchor">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Mobile</span>
    <div id="m-underline-div" class="underline-div"></div>
</a>
```

Then your JS:

```
$(".btn-anchor").on("click", function() {
    $( '.underline-div' ).css("background", "grey");
    $( this ).parent().find('.underline-div').css("background", "blue");
});
```

```js
$(".btn-anchor").on("click", function() {
    $( '.underline-div' ).css("background", "grey");
    $( this ).parent().find('.underline-div').css("background", "blue");
});
```

```css
.underline-div {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div id="m-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <div id="m-container-2">
   <a id="m-button" href="#15178671677277-96tu3e-3487" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="btn-anchor">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Mobile</span>
    <div id="m-underline-div" class="underline-div"></div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="l-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="l-button" href="#151746716339-c6ryaabc-d953" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="btn-anchor">
   <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Laptop</span>
   <div id="l-underline-div" class="underline-div"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
 
 <h1>More Itens options</h1>
 <div id="n-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="n-button" href="#url01" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="btn-anchor">
   <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Desktops</span>
   <div id="n-underline-div" class="underline-div"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="o-container" class="col-xs-6">
  <a id="o-button" href="#url04" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" class="btn-anchor">
   <span class="vc_tta-title-text">Printers</span>
   <div id="o-underline-div" class="underline-div"></div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```